# Overlay of two images with transparency

Tags: javascript, php, html, png

I'm looking for a solution in Javascript maybe to create a real-time preview of products based on multiple options that a consumer could choose from multiple radiobutton.

Exemple : I have a face.png and a hat.png with transparents parts, and a cap, and when I click on cap, I would like to display the image of the cap + the face and if I click on the buttonradio on hat, I would like to update my preview in real time and keep the face and only change the image of the hat (a png with transparency)

Do you have any idea how I could do this?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a container div and place face and hat inside of that div then position each other with position absolute

i added a function for changing hats
by clicking the thumbnail of hat user will change the src attribute of the actual hat image which we were showing

```js
let hats = [
  "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81B6-uzku8L._UX679_.jpg",
  "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/714/857/jiulk7k0/cap/g/r/v/free-hat-peter-india-original-imaf6gzbhh7pydzy.jpeg?q=50",
  "https://contents.mediadecathlon.com/p982435/31cf29c7f44e13d3f77af7bd205a303c/p982435.jpg"
];
let currentIndex = 0;


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{

  let thumpnails = document.querySelector('.thumpnails');
  hats.forEach((hat)=> {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = hat;
    img.classList.add('thumpnail');
    thumpnails.append(img);
    
    img.onclick= ()=>{showMe(hat)};
    
  });

})

function showMe(src){
  document.querySelector('.hatImg').src = src;
}

//document.querySelector('#next').addEventListener('click',next)
```

```css
.pic{
position:relative;
width:200px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid black;
}

.face{
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width:100px;
  background:red;
  bottom:25px;
  left:50px;
  
}
.hatImg{
  width:180px;
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  bottom:100px;
  opacity:0.8;
}

.thumpnail{
  width:50px;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <div class="face"></div>
  
  <img class="hatImg" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81B6-uzku8L._UX679_.jpg">
</div>
<div class="thumpnails"></div>
```

Comment: What means the a6 in the end of the rgb collors in css ?

Comment: Instead of a button how can I use checkbox ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: a6 is for transparency,

Comment: you can add a checkbox for each hat and when user clicks on the checkbox there will be an event called on change will be triggered you can change hat within that function

Comment: outside of the pic div with thumbnail of the hats you want to display or event you can do some stylings. i will update my answer accordingly

Comment: i have completely changed my code matching for your case, now there is a small thumbnail of hats shown in the bottom bar and user can click the image so that the actual big hat image will change accordingly